# No UseDatabaseErrorPage() extension method in Net Core 3.0

Tags: c#, .net, database, visual-studio, .net-core

I have created Net Core 3.0 app and following code that worked in 2.2 now is not.

```
app.UseDatabaseErrorPage();
```

Looks like in 3.0 class `DatabaseErrorPageExtensions` does not exist within `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder` namespace. Am I missing some dependency? I have EntityFrameworkCore NuGet with Tools and Design added.

Adding

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder;
```

not helped.

Comment: Tried reading msdn?
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/error-handling?view=aspnetcore-3.0#database-error-page
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-au/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.builder.databaseerrorpageextensions.usedatabaseerrorpage?view=efcore-2.1

Comment: Exactly, so this method should be but is not existing.

Answer (score 134, accepted):

Add a reference to 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.EntityFrameworkCore', it appears that function is in that package now.

Comment: Thanks, it worked also in my side, the main reason for this error is that after upgrading to .net core 3.1, you should get rid of Microsoft.AspNetCore.App NuGet package which has many dependencies. 
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.EntityFrameworkCore is one of the dependencies that we need to add individually in case we need them.

Comment: Works like charm! Thanks!

Comment: Worked for me. Thanks.

Answer (score 7):

use

```
Install-Package Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.EntityFrameworkCore -Version 3.1.5
```

Comment: Thanks Ali!
That sure turned out to be more clear & fruitful, i.e. requirement of installation of the said package's latest version (Currently 3.1.5), since inserting a simple using... statement only reflected as EFCore to be not existing in Diagnostics.

Answer (score 1):

[CLI]

`dotnet add package Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.EntityFrameworkCore --version 3.1.2`

[StartUp.cs]

`using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.EntityFrameworkCore;`

Comment: Your answer lacks clarity!